# Load files from Gem in Rake task

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, bundler

Using Bundler, Rails 3.1.0 and RVM-gemsets I want to load files from a defined Gem.

[`Gem.datadir(gem_name)`](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem.html#method-c-datadir) seems to be the right candidate but does not seem to work with RVM-gemsets.

**Addition:**
In my specific case I want to load YML Files. Obviously is Rails 3 able to extend `config.i18n.load_path` with paths and files from a gem as if they were lying within my app's root. How to they achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to require the gem before running `Gem#datadir`.